# ArrayLists and indexers in Java

Tags: c#, java, arrays, arraylist

Is it possible to do this in Java? Maybe I'm using the wrong syntax?

```
ArrayList<Integer> iAL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
iAL.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }));

for (int i = 0; i < iAL.size(); ++i) {
    System.out.println(iAL[i]); //<-------- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
}
```

Also, is it possible to do something like

```
iAL.addAll( new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} );
```

as is seen on c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `System.out.println(iAL.get(i));`. Because it's a `List`, not `array`

Comment: So Lists in Java can't use indexers? Probably it's related to Java not supporting Operator Overloading?

Comment: Yes, you are right, there are no indexers and no other stuff like this :(

Comment: Java does not support Operator Overloading so it is not possible to use the indexing operator ([]) for anything other than arrays.

Answer (score 4):

```
ArrayList<Integer> iAL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
iAL.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }));

for (int i = 0; i < iAL.size(); ++i) {
    System.out.println(iAL.get(i)); 
}
```

AFAIK

`iAL.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }));` // this is the shortest solution

Comment: Arrays.asList() accepts a varargs parameter, so it can be shorter.

Comment: Also, if you're just going to be immediately adding those elements, using the copy constructor can further shorten things.

Answer (score 4):

> Also, is it possible to do something like
>
> ```
> iAL.addAll( new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} );
> ```

Close enough:

```
iAL.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

No need for the `new Integer[]` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, I would add two other notes about your code:

- You may find the [for-each](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) syntax appealing.
- Consider the advantages of [coding to the interface](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1999/jw-08-interfaces.html).

For example, combining several helpful suggestions from other answers

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ));

for (Integer i : list) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Addendum: The question of [coding to the interface](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1999/jw-08-interfaces.html) is interesting, and [Carl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167973/carl)'s comment is particularly apropos. Using the interface type, `List`, minimizes your obligation to use a specific implementation. If the need arises, you can later switch to any [class that implements `List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: I don't get your second point(coding to the interface). What does it have to do with this?

Comment: declaring iAL as a List instead of an ArrayList.  unless you plan to use some of the size management methods in ArrayList, that's probably a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

No, you must use `.get(i)`; `[i]` is for arrays only.  However, if you don't need the index variable for something else, the for-each syntax is preferable (as per trashgod's answer).

For the second, if you aren't resizing the List (it is still fine to mutate individual elements), it would be perfectly reasonable to do the following:

```
List<Integer> iAL = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Note, that `Arrays.asList()` accepts a varargs parameter, so no reason to explicitly construct the array.

If you want a resizable List, the following is probably the shortest:

```
List<Integer> iAL = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Answer (score 2):

I will refactor your entire code to :

```
List<Integer> iAL = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );

for (int i : iAL) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```